# How do read a dataset from a URL into R?

Tags: r, url, dataset

Currently I'm trying to read various datasets located on the same location on my PC.

They end up looking something like this (except the URL is much larger):

```
Data_1 <- read_xlsx('C:/Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/Data_1.xlsx')
Data_2 <- read_xlsx('C:/Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/Data_2.xlsx')
Data_3 <- read_xlsx('C:/Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/Data_3.rds')
Data_4 <- read_xlsx('C:/Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/Data_4.rds')
```

I find this is impractical and hard to read.
Im trying an alternative like the following:

```
URL="'C:/Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/"
Data_1 <- read_xlsx(paste(URL)'Data_1.xlsx')
Data_2 <- read_xlsx(paste(URL)'Data_2.xlsx')
Data_3 <- readRDS(paste(URL)'Data_3.rds')
Data_4 <- readRDS(paste(URL)'Data_4.rds')
```

However I cant get it to work, it's probably something simple but i can't figure it out.
How do you handle this?

Comment: It should be `paste0(URL, 'Data_1.xlsx')`. First, you are closing the `paste` function before assigin the filename. Second because `paste` will add a space between the strings, and `paste0` will just concatenate them with no separator.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you could do this.

**First: set your working directory and then access them.**

```
URL = "C:/Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXX"
# set working directory
setwd(URL)

# read your data
Data_1 <- read_xlsx('Data_1.xlsx')
```

**Second: Use path to create a path**

```
Data_1 <- read_xlsx(file.path(URL, 'Data_1.xlsx'))
```

**Third: more intuitive to use `paste0`**

```
Data_1 <- read_xlsx(paste0(URL,"/, 'Data_1.xlsx'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this will come handy in the future!